# read current culture of asp.net mvc project and change language in javascript confirm

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, culture, confirm

I have a javascript confirm. My text is in english, but if I will change language/culture of my asp.net mvc project confirm is of cource  still english.

I can controll it manually and just write two javascript methods (for both Languages) but it is no so clean I think. And if I will have more than 3 languages its will be more dirty.

Could you give me some Tip how can i solve my problem?

Best for me is to have confirm with some metatag or something where can i give my text from resource files out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script language="javascript">
var confirmMessage = "<%= localizedConfirmMessage %>";

// use confirmMessage when showing confirm popup
...
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do seperate js file with strings only, e.g.:

```
var MultilanguageStrings = {
    'savingConfirmation': {
        'en': 'Do you want to save changes?',
        'pl': 'Czy chcesz zapisać zmiany?'
    },
    'fatalError': {
        'en': 'Fatal error occured.',
        'pl': 'Wystąpił krytyczny błąd.'
    },
    'get': function (key, lang) {
        if (this[key] === undefined)
            return 'Error. There is no such message.';
        if (lang == 'en' && this[key]['en'] === undefined)
            return 'Error. There is no such message.';
        if (this[key][lang] === undefined)
            return this.get(key, 'en');
        return this[key][lang];
    }
};
```

And than make dynamically generated js file with information which language is set:

```
var currentLanguage = 'en';
```

You can also get this information by different way (e.g. AJAX) but solution above has this advantage, that your code is already loaded and `currentLanguage` is set.

Then in your code put:

```
...
if (confirm(MultilanguageStrings.get('savingConfirmation', currentLanguage))) {
...
```

You may want to wrap everything into 1 global variable, that would be more neat.
Also remember not to overwrite method `MultilanguageStrings.get`.